Magento graphQl product query (width, height, weight)
I have a store on Magento 2. I don't have much experience with graphQL, so I'm asking for help, tips on how to formulate a graphQL query.
I need to get the dimensions of the product, i.e. length, width, height, weight.
My query:
query Products {
    products(
       search: "Samsung"
       pageSize: 100
    ) {
       total_count
       items {
         sku
         name
         catalog_number
         description{
           html
         }
         width
         height
       }
       page_info {
          page_size
          current_page
       }
    } }

The query returns an error. What am I doing wrong, where is the error?
Second question: how can I modify the query to retrieve product attributes (core, diameter, color)?
Thanks for any help or advice
